# Uniform bound on the measure of $\Omega_\delta = \Omega \cap \delta\mathbb Z^d$ if $\Omega$ is an open bounded set with Lipschitz boundary

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, na.numerical-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ be an open bounded set with Lipschitz boundary. Let us consider $\Omega_\delta = \Omega \cap \delta\mathbb Z^d$ for $\delta >0$. I want to say that the measure of $\Omega_\delta$ is bounded by a constant which is independent of $\delta$ and somehow depending only on the original $\Omega$.

How can this be proved? I guess it is a classical result in numerical analysis, but I can't find  a reference.

My motivation is this: suppose that we prove a discrete Poincaré inequality in $\Omega_\delta$. Then I want to get out of it the "continuous" Poincaré inequality without the measure of the domain blowing up in the limit. Does it make sense?

Comment: The set $\Omega$ is open where? And what measure do you mean? And you probably mean something different than “$\Omega\cap \delta\mathbb{Z}$”, since $ \delta\mathbb{Z}$  is a countable subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes, sorry. I meant $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ and the typo is that the post should read $\mathbb Z^d$

Comment: @PietroMajer And I suppose that the appropriate mesure would be the one that counts the points in $\Omega_\delta$

Comment: It seems a bit odd to expect a bound independent of $\delta$, no? I would think that $\lvert \Omega \cap \delta \mathbf{Z}^d \rvert$ would grow like $\delta^{-d}$.

Comment: @LeoMoos My motivation is this: suppose that we prove a discrete Poincaré inequality in $\Omega_\delta$. Then I want to get out of it the "continuous" Poincaré inequality without the measure of the domain blowing up in the limit. Does it make sense?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't completely understand. Perhaps you could add a few lines to the question, showcasing what you're trying to do when $d = 1$ and $\Omega = (0,1)$.

Comment: @Hiro is it clear to you that if $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^1$ is a non empty open set, it contains a non empty  interval $[a,b]$ and then at least $\lfloor\frac{b-a}{\delta}\rfloor$ points of $\delta\mathbb Z^1$?

Comment: You need to provide more details. For example you did not explain what measure you have in $\Omega_\delta$. Otherwise your question might be closed.